# secure way to transfer user passwords in php

Tags: c#, php, encryption, public-key-encryption, password-encryption

Hi I am googling these days to find a better way to send user info(including password) through the internet. Our servers don't have SSL installed. so need a very simple and secure method to send user info. In future my boss want to expand it to connect with desktop applications written in .net(C#). so the methods should be compatible with .net also. I need a advice or any thing that I can get a good  idea for developing a better solution.

Comment: Encrypt it with a password only you, and the destination server know. Something really long, like 128-bits or something.

Comment: @donutdan4114 Where do you plan to store that password?

Comment: Two pieces of advice; 1) Don't design your own pseudo secure solution. Designing something secure costs more than just plain changing over to SSL. 2) If you still want to design a secure system, don't do it by asking random people on the Internet how to do it.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson I like the second one. :) but the company is not own by me. so with the limited resources I have, need to do the job.

Comment: @L.B - I don't know anything about their current setup, especially how they are storing the passwords. The most obvious solution to me, would be to store using a sha1 hash with salt. Both programs (servers) should be able to store passwords in the same way. So the hashing method should be the same. To transfer the passwords they should be encrypted, although not as important if the sha1 hash is using a secret salt. Basically, just don't send plain text passwords over the interwebz.

Comment: @donutdan4114 so you say, if I find the  hashed password and send to the server, I can log in?

Comment: @L.B - If both devices are using the same hashing method than yes. Your password on one server, will hash the same as on the other server.

Comment: @donutdan4114 I meant it as a security bug.

Comment: @L.B - You would not be able to login using the hash (if you hacked and found the hash). You would need to know the original string that created the hash.

Comment: @donutdan4114 the server can't also find the password given the hashed password even if it knows the algorithm and the salt. Hashing is an irreversable function.

Comment: @donutdan4114 See other comments and answers and don't try to device a new system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1. Use TLS/SSL. Really. A web server certificate can be obtained for free these days.
2. Use TLS/SSL. I really mean it. Don't be naive thinking that you can do a home brew solution, no matter which complex encryption algorithm you can imagine, that can outperform the legacy secure and easy of implementation as TLS/SSL is.
3. To solve a scenario with web clients and desktop clients, you should take a look at [OAuth](http://oauth.net/).

Comment: Thanks... TLS/SSL for free!! Thats a good news. I'll definitely have look at the OAuth.

Comment: There's probably plenty of offerings out there, but one of them is http://www.startssl.com/ , another is Comodo http://www.comodo.com/business-security/digital-certificates/free-ssl.php

Answer (score 1):

If you mean sending the password from a login form to the server in a secure way, there is nothing better than SSL. You could try implementing a system like Public key encryption, but I think it would be easier to enable SSL...

To store the passwords, simply use an encryption function like sha1

If you mean authenticating users in a desktop application you could implement [oauth](http://oauth.net/) for example, which is not very hard and provides a very safe way of doing so.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is called [Digest authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) and quite easy to implement.

However, to use it you have to store passwords in plain text, you can't use it with hashes.
Which, in my point of view, makes it completely impossible to use.

Answer (score 0):

1 curl (simple)
2 md5 encryption POST method
3 web service (complex)